# How can I use the sql function CAST in rust, diesel?

Tags: mysql, rust, rust-diesel

I'm developing a new endpoint using Rocket and am trying to return a Vec<> made of various structs.

The raw query I want to replicate in diesel is:

```
select location.id, location.name, w.datetime, t.temp, w.compass, w.speed, r.probability, s.height
from location
inner join rainfall r on location.id = r.location
inner join temperature t on location.id = t.location
inner join wind w on location.id = w.location
inner join swell s on location.id = s.location
where t.datetime = w.datetime
  and s.datetime = t.datetime
  and CAST(t.datetime as date) = CAST(r.datetime as date)
  and t.datetime > now() and t.datetime < NOW() + INTERVAL 1 HOUR;
```

and I recognize, that in order to use the CAST function I need to use the [sql_function!](https://docs.diesel.rs/diesel/macro.sql_function.html) macro:

```
sql_function! {
#[sql_name="CAST"]
    fn cast(x: sql_types::Nullable<sql_types::Datetime>) -> sql_types::Date;
}
```

which allows me to create the following query:

```
let summaries: Vec<(Location, Swell, Wind, Temperature, Rainfall)> = location::table
        .inner_join(swell::table)
        .inner_join(wind::table)
        .inner_join(temperature::table)
        .inner_join(rainfall::table)
        .filter(temperature::datetime.eq(wind::datetime))
        .filter(temperature::datetime.eq(swell::datetime))
        .filter(temperature::datetime.gt(utilities::today()))
        .filter(temperature::datetime.lt(utilities::future_hour(1)))
        .filter(cast(temperature::datetime).eq(cast(rainfall::datetime)))
        .load(&conn.0)?;
```

However, when I run this query I get a SQL Query error:

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near \') = CAST('rainfall'.'datetime')\' at line 1"

As illustrated in the raw SQL statement it should read `CAST('rainfall'.'datetime' as date)`.

My question is, how can I add the 'as date' component to my diesel query? Is something missing in the sql_function definition?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer after digging a little deeper into similar questions.

Turns out you can enter a raw sql string into the `.filter` method after adding: `use diesel::expression::sql_literal::sql;`.

So the final snippet becomes:

```
let summaries: Vec<(Location, Swell, Wind, Temperature, Rainfall)> = location::table
        .inner_join(swell::table)
        .inner_join(wind::table)
        .inner_join(temperature::table)
        .inner_join(rainfall::table)
        .filter(temperature::datetime.eq(wind::datetime))
        .filter(temperature::datetime.eq(swell::datetime))
        .filter(temperature::datetime.gt(utilities::today()))
        .filter(temperature::datetime.lt(utilities::future_hour(1)))
        .filter(sql("CAST(`temperature`.`datetime` as date) = CAST(`rainfall`.`datetime` as date)"))
        .load(&conn.0)?;
```

I hope this helps someone else!

Comment: Is it possible to enter a raw sql into `.select()` for using `to_char` method? For example: `select to_char(date_field, 'YYYY-MM') from table_name` in Diesel ORM